# Facing CORS policy issue on lambda

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So my use case is I'm sending a post request to lambda with some credentials and that credentials I'm using it to authenticate with third-party application and sending the data as a response to frontend but while sending post request I'm facing cors issue but while doing get a request I'm not getting cors issue.

I have used vpc and sometimes it gives me

> "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.157.139.105:443
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16) " this error in lambda when it tries to post request to third party api.

Mine lambda code is:

```
case "GET": {
      let response = await checkStatus();
      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data : response
        })
      }
    }
    case "POST": {
      let { queryStringParameters, body } = event;
      if (queryStringParameters.target === "projectOptions") {
        let response = await getProjectOptions(JSON.parse(body));
        if (response.data) {
          return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              data : response.data
            })
          }
        }
      }
```

and im fetching it from localhost like

```
    const response:any = await fetch(`${SDL_URL}?target=projectOptions`, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(config)
});
let data = await response.json();
```

Can you please help me here I'm stuck on this for the past week?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: I suspect the timeout error is from `getProjectOptions`? In your shown code you are not catching any exceptions and only setting the correct CORS headers in case of success. So when your lambda ends because of an exception you don't have any CORS headers, thus the CORS error ...

Comment: Be aware that you cannot use the wildcard (`*`) in conjunction with credentialed requests; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards. Also, because you're using `application/json` as your request's content type, [you need to allow the `Content-Type` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests): `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type`.

Comment: @derpirscher im catching the error but still same issue im facing also i tried from postman it is giving me {
    "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}" this error

Comment: i think it is because im using vpc and it is not able to connect to internet something ?

Comment: Well yes, it might be, that the lambda function isn't able to connect to that third party API. But that has nothing to do with CORS. Because CORS only applies between browser and backend (ie your browser and your lambda function)

Comment: i tried adding catch but still im facing the issue.

Comment: Are you adding correct CORS headers after catching the exception? And catching an exception does not magically resolve the error.

Comment: i have added the correct CORS headers .tried adding allow-headers also still facing the same issue.

Comment: have your read @jub0bs comment about credentials and wildcards? (not sure if you are sending credentials, though). What issue are you talking about? The CORS error or the timeout?

Comment: facing both etimedout and cors issue i think maybe because frontend sends request and in 30 second if lambda is not able to send response than it gives error and because of that . have you worked on lambda function vpc setup?

Comment: it's obviously not a connection issue because GET is working fine, what i suspect POST is not added as CROS option list at TP end or some sever error is happening at TP side, sometimes 500 server error hide behind cros error, it's dont show the actual issue in error trace, please check with TP client.

Comment: @MrOverflow sometimes it works but most of the time it gives me "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.157.139.105:443" while getting response from third party api i have added post in cors option list but still same problem persist.

Comment: it you are making a REST call to " third party api " then they have to enable CROS at their end, it's not at your side.  if you are getting response back for some request but  majority of  other request you are getting timeout, then definitely check with "third party provider", or check network connectivity.